# Is wrong nine patch image?

Tags: android, selector, shadow, nine-patch

I brought two nine patch images from designer for action-bar list item background. But outside of item is black.

I add images in "android:itemBackground".
The below images have shadow effect.
I think the image is wrong because it has margin.
I wonder what is exact cause?

thank.

[image]

Image1:

[image]

Image2:

[image]

Comment: http://postimg.org/image/a26k89hof/

Comment: http://postimg.org/image/hh0x39o0x/

Comment: http://postimg.org/image/jesne1hc3/

Answer (score 0):

I think the designer intend to make shadow effect by using bg image. Because other app's overflow menu have shadow effect. But the effect is shown by framework. So I used an color drawable as background.